# Translation portion 4×4 transformation matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, webgl, transformation

There is some major (no pun intended) confusion for me about row major and column major matrices.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18901/can-someone-explain-the-reasons-for-the-implications-of-colum-vs-row-major-in

In the above article it is stated that( for a column matrix) the translation portion is in indices 12, 13, and 14. In the 3D math primer for graphics and gamedevelopment book it is stated that they are in indices 3, 7 and 11.

So, i'm trying to build a matrix class. My array is layed out as follows:

```
[ xx, yx, zx, 0, xy, yy, zy, 0, xz, yz, zz, 0, xT, yT, zT, 1]
```

My question is, is this the righ way to lay out a column major matrix? or should it be layed out like one of the following?

```
[ xx, xy, xz, xT, yx, yy, yz, yT, zx, zy, zz, zT, 0, 0, 0, 1]

[ xx, yx, zx, xT, xy, yy, zy, yT, xz, yz, zz, zT, 0, 0, 0, 1]

[ xx, xy, xz, 0, yx, yy, yz, 0, zx, zy, zz, 0, xT, yT, zT, 1]
```

Edit to make the question more clear:

I pass my matrix to the next function (as an Array)

```
 gl.uniformMatrix4fv( shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix );
```

The question is: in what of the 4 orders ( explained above) does this method expect the matrix to be? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn302458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

the documentation doesn't say anything about order, only about transposing the whole matrix. But how do i know if i have to transpose it, if i don't know what it would normaly expect.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you recreating `glRotate()` and `glTranslate()`?

Comment: No, i'm working in Javascript / webGL. The glMatrix.js which is commonly used is completely unreadable, and i have some JS tricks that i can use to improve on it. Also, in the glMatrix it seems that order doesn't matter: identity * rotation * translation = identity * translation * rotation. I mean to fix this.

Comment: I suggest you update your tags, and mention on the title a 4×4 transformation matrix, since a 3D matrix usually refers to rotation only.

Comment: Good idea, i was having problems thinking of a good title and picking tags.

Comment: I edited your tags also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter? There are 2 things often conflated in 3D math libraries. Column vs Row storage and separately how those elements are used.

Most libraries that I've used store the data as you've written it.

```
[ xx, yx, zx, 0, xy, yy, zy, 0, xz, yz, zz, 0, xT, yT, zT, 1]
```

or another way to picture it

```
[ xAxis, 0,
  yAxis, 0,
  zAxis, 0,
  translation, 1]
```

They then provide matrix functions. If you changed the storage format you could easily change the functions to so the behavior didn't change. It's only if you allow direct access to the elements of the matrix that storage format matters and then you can still choose whatever format you want, you just have to tell you users what that format is.

As an example with the format as it is above a typical GLSL shader might have code like this

```
gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * a_position;
```

If you switched the order to

```
[ xx, yx, zx, xT, xy, yy, zy, yT, xz, yz, zz, zT, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

You'd just change the GLSL to

```
gl_Position = a_position * u_worldViewProjection;
```

On the other hand, since (at least from my experience), most libraries store their matrixes the same as the top example it seems like a good idea to do the same?

Comment: Yeah that depends on how this mat4 uniform is used. Generally a vec4 is regarded as a matrix with four rows and one column, so a mat4 is put on the left when multiplied.

Comment: So then it does matter. The function i was talking about accesses the elements directly probably, right? By the way, i also found out that my matrix-vector multiplication doesn't work when i store the translation portion in 12, 13, and 14. I checked the function that multiplies them, but have found no mistakes ( matrix on the left, vector on the right )

Comment: [Here's a library with both styles](https://github.com/greggman/tdl/blob/master/tdl/math.js). You can choose column major or row major for the various function or call the column or row major functions directly.

Comment: Thanks. i haven't had the chance to look at your library at a very specific level, but i'm pretty sure, that this + your other comment will answer my question. Cheers!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, the library is awesome, however, i'm still building my own. Mostly because of this:

 m = tdl.math.matrix4.identity();
 tdl.math.matrix4.translate( m, [10,20,30]);
 tdl.math.matrix4.rotateX( m, 90*(Math.PI/180 ) );

 n = Matrix3D(); 
 n.translate( 10, 20, 30 );
 n.rotate([1,0,0], 90);

As you can see, my syntax is much more readable. If you're interested, i can send you the first results when i'm done :)

Answer (score -1):

The transformation matrix is such that

```
| R  v | | p | = | v + R*p |
| 0  1 | | 1 |   | 1       |
```

which is interpreted as translate first by `v`, then rotate by `R`. So if you take the rows of the transformation matrix you have

```
| R11 R12 R13 v1 |
| R21 R22 R23 v2 | -> [R11,R12,R13,v1,R21,R22,R23,v2,...]
| R31 R32 R33 v3 |
|  0   0   0  1  |
```

All you have to do to confirm this is do a translation by `(1,2,3)` and then use `glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix)` to probe the data.

reference: http://relativity.net.au/gaming/java/ModelViewMatrix.html

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of your answer. I'm not yet familiar with any gl methods. The tutorials i read about WebGL don't use these, and just bind the matrices in Float32Array form. On top of that, i'm not sure how it answers my question.

Comment: Nitpick: It is rotate first, then translate, since translate first, then rotate would have the formula R(v+p).

Comment: I will rephrase the question a bit, to make it more clear what i want to know.

Comment: You'll note that while you've written a column major *mathy* version of a matrix in memory the GL matrix is `[xAxis.x, xAxis.y, xAxis.z, 0, xAxis.x, xAxis.y, xAxis.z, 0, xAxis.x, xAxis.y, xAxis.z, 0, translation.x, translation.y, translation.z, 1]` which you can verify by calling get `glTranslate` and then probing the matrix. You'll see the translation is stored in elements 12, 13, 14 and not elements 3, 7, 11. [See example here](https://gist.github.com/greggman/9047289)